# Want to display more than one data retrieved from mysql database in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/amd", "root", "");
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select *from neighbour_node where node_name='" + nodename + "' ");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {

    String neigh = rs.getString(2);
    jTextField1.setText(neigh);
}
```

And my database

```
node_name:       a b b

node_neighbour:  b a c
```

if my input is "a" then display "b" as neighbour node.

if my input is "b" then display "a" & "c" as neighbour node.

but in my code for input "b" it only display "c" as neighbour node.

how to correct my code to display more than one data.

Comment: You are currently selecting all columns, which probably is a bad idea.  Please update your question and show us table structure along with your expected output.

Comment: You might want to consider what `jTextField1.setText` does... You overwrite the values and only the last value returned is shown. Instead you might want to construct a list of values, and only call `jTextField1.setText` **after** the loop.

Comment: PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select *from neighbour_node where node_name='"+nodename+"' ");

Comment: PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select *from neighbour_node where node_name='"+nodename+"' ");                                                    For example, the above query retrieve to matching data say for nodename "b" it retrieve 2 data say "a" and "c".                               while(rs.next())    
             String neigh=rs.getString(2);
             jTextField1.setText(neigh);
 in this code i'm using single textfield to display the result. as per my requirement if the query retrieve more than one data from database how can i display it my jframe.

Comment: you can use JTable instead to jtextfield you can take a look here http://imss-www.upmf-grenoble.fr/prevert/Prog/Java/swing/JTable.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're looking for JTable [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), or maybe create a new JTextField each time.

EDIT : I agree with @Tim, selecting everything might be a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List<String>` instead of a `String` for example :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

while(rs.next()){
    list.add(rs.getString(2));
}
```

So like this you can get a list of String and you can show it with a Simple loop :

```
for(String s : list){
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Note**

Because you are using `PreparedStatement` why you don't use `?` like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = 
       con.prepareStatement("select * from neighbour_node where node_name = ?");
ps.SetString(1, nodename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh? You use

```
jTextField1.setText(neigh);
```

in a while loop. Of course it gets overwritten every time and you get only the last value found. You should collect all values in one string and set the field at the end.